# minikube && kubectl - k8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes

На винде пытаюсь разобраться с k8s. Есть Docker Desktop, в котором включен K8s. Вот только во всех туториалах используется призрачный minikube...

Minikube как я понял - это образ на докере с дэшбордом + отдельно kubeadm, kubectl и тд.

Но у меня уже из Docker Desktop есть kubectl... Я просто запутался, объясните нужен ли мне вообще minikube, что конкретно он делает (как я понял, это просто рабочая среда для k8s), чем отличается от k8s в docker desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`minikube` - это не образ в докере, а наоборот, это виртуальная машина (установленная в `Hyper-V` или `VirtualBox`, т.к. для работы `docker` нужен `Linux Kernel`), внутри которой установлен `Docker` и `Kubernetes` (по факту `minikube` это один из многих способов локально развернуть `Kubernetes`, который в разы проще, чем самому поднимать виртуалки и через `kubeadm` разворачивать `Kubernetes`), если вы только разбираетесь с `Kubernetes`, то я думаю большой разницы для вас не будет, что использовать большинство команд должны работать одинаково.

Преимушества `Docker Desktop` в том, что это решение, которое включается все сразу и `Docker` и `Kubernetes`, это возможно упрошает работу с ним в начале, т.к. когда вы устанавливаете и `Docker` и `minikube`, то по факту вы ставите 2 докера, т.е. ставится 2 виртуалки, одна с докером, вторая вместе `minikube` и нужно это учитывать  (т.е. они "не знают" ничего друг о друге) или использовать только докер из миникуба: `eval $(minikube docker-env)`. Так же в `Docker Desktop` реализован `LoadBalancer` для `Services`, что может быть иногда может быть полезно.

`minikube` быстрее обновляется на последней версии `Kubernetes` (а также позволяет относительно легко разворачивать отдельные/старые версии), есть поддержка addons (но по факту это просто набор `yaml` файлов, т.е. их можно развернуть и в `Docker Desktop`, сюда такде входит `dashboard`, да в `minikube` он сразу есть и запустить его можно одной командой, но в `Docker Desktop` его тоже не тяжело развернуть). По субъективным ощущениям он стабильнее, чем `Docker Desktop`, т.к. пару раз приходилось сбрасывать все настройки по не понятным причинам.

`kubectl` - ставится в обоих случаях (это просто один исполняемый файл, который можно скачать с сайта и положить куда угодно), который позволяет вам отправлять команды в разные инстансы `Kubernetes`, например, если у вас есть локальный инстанс и где-то в облаке (`AWS`, `Azure` и т.д.).

Если у вас уже включен `Kubernetes` в `Docker Desktop`, то рядом запушенный `minikube` не нужен, но поставить оба вам никто не запрешает и пользоваться по очереди и понять, что вам больше нравится/подходит.